# Spamassassin disable spam information raports

Tags: spamassassin

I use SAWin32 (AKA SpamAssassin for Win32) with Microsoft Exchange 2000.

My users are receiving the following information concerning incoming messages that may be spam:

```
"This mail is probably spam. The original message
has been attached intact in RFC 822 format."
```

How do I completely disable the sending of this information to my users?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this in your "local.cf" file, set the "report_safe" variable to "0":

In my case:

**/etc/spamassassin/local.cf**

```
report_safe 0
```

---

**References**

http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.3.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.txt